# Alfresco 5.0.a - custom search facet

Tags: search, share, alfresco, faceted-search

I'd like to add some custom facets to the Alfresco (version 5.0.a) search page. I've created an extension which allows to override already created facets:

```
<import resource="classpath:/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/share/imports/share-header.lib.js">
<import resource="classpath:/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/share/imports/share-footer.lib.js">
var facet = widgetUtils.findObject(model.jsonModel, "id", "FCTSRCH_FACET_DESCRIPTION");
facet.config.label = "Document type";
facet.config.facetQName = "{http://www.someComp.com/model/comp/1.0}personGroup";
```

But it is not the right way I think.
The problem is that I cannot override the parent widgets, since they don't have ids (faceted-search.get.js). 
How do I manage to add a custom facet to the model?

---

Another question is regarding parameter of the facet with name `facetQName`. In the same file (faceted-search.get.js) I met some strange syntax which I don't understand.
Some examples:

```
facetQName: "{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}creator.__.u",
facetQName: "{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}modifier.__.u",
facetQName: "{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}description.__",
```

What do these `.__.u` and `.__` suffixxes mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I finally solve the problem. 
Just for clarification: I had a requirement to use 5.0.a version in which there is no Search Manager page.
The solution which I used is a bit dirty, but it worked. I just overwrite the faceted-search.get.js and changed the facets array by adding my custom metadata:

```
// Compose the individual facets
var facets = [
...
{
id: "FCTSRCH_FACET_DOCUMENT_TYPE",
name: "alfresco/search/FacetFilters",
config: {
  label: "Document Type",
  facetQName: "{http://www.mycomp.com/model/efiles/1.0}typeName.__.u",
  sortBy: "ALPHABETICALLY",
  hitThreshold: 1,
  minFilterValueLength: 5,
  maxFilters: 10,
  useHash: false
}
...
```

If you are interested in details you can check this post: http://streetturtle.github.io/2015/01/20/faceted-search-alf-5-0-a/